Use of scipy.optimize
I am using Python in FEA a solver and i have an objective function to minimize. I thought about using scipy.optimize but it doesn't work. No optimization is carried out and no errors either... See just after, the function is working very well but no optimisation from minimize whatever the method used...
>>> fonction_calcul(1)
106,691348022978
>>> fonction_calcul(0.5)
99,4888918302546
>>> fonction_calcul(0.3)
90,7397102848129
>>> res = minimize(fonction_calcul,0.5,method='BFGS',options={'xtol': 1e-5,'disp': True})
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 99.488892
         Iterations: 0
         Function evaluations: 2
         Gradient evaluations: 1

The value which minimize should be 0.027 and as you see it stays blocked at the initial value and consider the optimization sucessfully done...
I have tried different methods...

Can you include the values of fonction_calcul(0.5) and fonction_calcul(0.50000001) in your question?

Please also provide fonction_calcul, to allow others to repeat your issue.

Dear Nick and Andrew, I moved forward a bit on this subject. Apparently, the issue was due to the fact that the epsilon function for the derivation calculation was too low and the Jacobian calculated by the function was null. By modifying this espilon value, it works better :). Now i need to find the best epsilon value !

If someone encounters the same issue, there is a solution : res = minimize(fonction_calcul,1,method="BFGS",options={"eps":1e-3, "disp":True})

@PierreLechevalier You should post that as a self-answer, so it shows up as answered in the question list.

If someone encounters the same issue, there is a solution:
res = minimize(fonction_calcul,1,method="BFGS",options={"eps":1e-3, "disp":True})

